# how to convert int to vector<int>?

Tags: c++

When I assign int to vector I get an error says  "`conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' requested`", what should I do? 
I have **vector varr(4, -1)**; what is the right way to do "**varr[2] = 3**"?

Comment: This is like asking "how do I turn a slice of bread into a loaf?"

Comment: you have to add to vector not assign

Comment: You need to elaborate. Explain the logic of what you are trying to do. How would you conceivably convert a single lone integer to an expanding collection of integers? The closest thing I can think of is to do `vector<int> v; v.push_back(myIntVariable);`

Comment: Regarding the edit: what exactly doesn't work for you with `vector<int> varr(4, -1); varr[2] = 3;`? It should be fine, and it sets the third element of `varr` to 3.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the smallest segment of code that reproduces your error and for you to post the error messages you are getting as well. Also, it would be helpful to know which compiler you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're two different types.  If you want to add an `int` to a `vector<int>` do something like:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(10);
```

**Update:** To set an element within the vector:

```
std::vector<int> vec(16, 0); // Create a 16 element vector containing all 0's
vec[4] = 10; // Sets the 5th element (0 based arrays) to 10
```

There appears to be a thorough [codeguru tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027) which might be of interest.

Comment: but push_back() will just do appending, I want to insert into a a certain position.

Comment: @baboonWorksFine: "I want to insert into a a certain position" -- please add that to your question!

Comment: @baboonWorksFine: Then you use insert(). But you don't really want to insert() on a vector very often for performance reasons. (You would use a list instead.)

Comment: @baboonWorksFine:  vector's deal with continuous memory chunks.  If you want to insert a 6th element in a vector, there must already be 5 elements in the vector.  If you want an associative collection, you will want to use something like `std::map` instead.

Comment: @andand change `std::vector` to `std::vector<int>` in your second code

Comment: @Ashot Martirosyan: Done.  Thanks.

Comment: @baboonWorksFine: Post the smallest segment of code that reproduces your error and post the error message you are getting as well.  Also, it would be helpful to know which compiler you're using.

Answer (score 3):

A vector is a collection of ints. You can not assign an int to the collection, you add it to the collection using the push_back() function:

```
std::vector<int> manyInts;
int oneInt = 42;
manyInts.push_back(oneInt);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the `int` to to a `vector<int>` you should use `push_back`:

```
vector<int> v;
int i = 5;
v.push_back(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int sum = 468;
vector<int> v;
while(sum!=0){
 v.push_back(sum%10);
        sum /= 10;
    }
reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: Perhaps you posted your answer to the wrong question.